# Ruby Watir-webdriver profile switching

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using Watir-Webdriver with Firefox profiles and I hit a bit of a snag. I am trying to figure out I may change various profile settings on the browser without closing and reopening it. I can find all the settings in `about:config` but I can seem to get Watir to navigate in there correctly to set the items I want. Alternatively, I cannot find any documentation about reloading profiles with new configuration values while the browser is still running.

So my question is, how may one easily navigate the about:config page itself to change configuration settings, or reload a profile object while the browser is still running.

Alternatively the settings I am looking for can also be found in the options GUI, but I don't think Watir can manipulate that.

Any help or tips will be appreciated.

Edit:: On a side note, if anyone sees this... is it possible to pull the current proxy ip that is used in the browser object returned from `Watir::Browser.new`

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you can modify configuration settings, but you  **CANNOT** load different profile without restarting the browser. This is something you can't do even manually.
Personally, I created a profile configuration once (manually), that is dedicated to tests and then I use it as it is.